# Converting a row from an astropy table to a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, astropy

I have a numpy table

```
<Table length=3>
  a     b  
int64 int64
----- -----
    1     3
    2     5
    4     7
```

And I would like to convert a row to a numpy array. But when I try, I end up with an array with no dimensions

```
In: np.array(mytable[0]).shape
Out: ()
```

and if I do

```
myrow = mytable[0]
myrow[0]
```

I get the error

```
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Is there something like `t[0].values` I could do, that would return `array([1, 3])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you slice a row from a table in Astropy and convert to an `ndarray`, you get a `0D` structured array back, which is the shape attribute is empty.  For a general solution, `numpy` provides a `structured_to_unstructured` method that will work well for more than just a single row slice as well.

---

```
>>> np.lib.recfunctions.structured_to_unstructured(np.array(t[0]))
array([1, 3])

>>> np.lib.recfunctions.structured_to_unstructured(np.array(t[1:]))
array([[2, 5],
       [4, 7]])
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Table.Row` object provides an iterator over the values, so you could do:

```
>>> np.array(list(t[0]))
array([1, 3])
```